# Cannot install gnome-terminal due to problems with gconf2

Tags: gnome-terminal, gconf

I was having problems with starting gnome-terminal, so I tried to remove and reinstall it. Running `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal` gives me the following result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gnome-terminal-data
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/171 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,953 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-terminal-data.
(Reading database ... 747935 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-terminal-data_3.6.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-terminal-data (3.6.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-terminal.
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-terminal_3.6.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-terminal (3.6.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--unpack):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 245
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gconf2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Trying to run `gnome-terminal` gives me the following errors:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

(gnome-terminal:28167): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get: the format string may not contain '&' (key 'monospace-font-name' from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface'). This call will probably stop working with a future version of glib.
GConf Error: Configuration server couldn't be contacted: D-BUS error: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
GConf Error: Configuration server couldn't be contacted: D-BUS error: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
GConf Error: Configuration server couldn't be contacted: D-BUS error: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
GConf Error: Configuration server couldn't be contacted: D-BUS error: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
GConf Error: Configuration server couldn't be contacted: D-BUS error: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
GConf Error: Configuration server couldn't be contacted: D-BUS error: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
**
ERROR:terminal-app.c:1449:terminal_app_init: assertion failed: (app->default_profile_id != NULL)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any idea what I can do to figure out what's going wrong? I'm currently using xfce4-terminal for my terminal in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this might be a roundabout way of doing things, but I've managed to get `gnome-terminal` running.

Since I was on 14.04 LTS, Ubuntu serendipitously gave me a prompt to upgrade to 16.04 LTS. Having backed everything up, I decided to just go ahead with the upgrade. 45 minutes later, `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal` works, and so does `gnome-terminal`.

For anyone else that needs help with this issue, I guess what I'm saying is to just do an upgrade or reinstall. This has been a frustrating week.